# No Symbols Loaded: libmex.pdb not loaded (throw_segv_longjmp_seh_filter() = EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH : C++ exception)

Tags: matlab, exception, visual-c++, mex, pdb-files

In order to create a `MEX function` and use it in my `MATLAB` code, like this:

```
[pow,index] = mx_minimum_power(A11,A12,A13,A22,A23,A33);
```

I've created the file `mx_minimum_power.cpp` and written the following code in it:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <complex>
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include "cvm.h"
#include "blas.h"
#include "cfun.h"

using std::complex;
using namespace cvm;

/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    const int arraysize = 62172;
    const int matrixDimention = 3;
    float *inMatrixA11 = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    complex<float> *inMatrixA12 = (complex<float> *)mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    complex<float> *inMatrixA13 = (complex<float> *)mxGetPr(prhs[2]);
    float *inMatrixA22 = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[3]);
    complex<float> *inMatrixA23 = (complex<float> *)mxGetPr(prhs[4]);
    float *inMatrixA33 = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[5]);
    basic_schmatrix< float, complex<float> > A(matrixDimention);
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < arraysize; i++)
    {
        A.set(1, 1, inMatrixA11[i]);
        A.set(1, 2, inMatrixA12[i]);
        A.set(1, 3, inMatrixA13[i]);
        A.set(2, 2, inMatrixA22[i]);
        A.set(2, 3, inMatrixA23[i]);
        A.set(3, 3, inMatrixA33[i]);
    }
}
```

And then in order to be able to debug the code, I've created the `mx_minimum_power.pdb` and `mx_minimum_power.mexw64` files, using the following code in the `Matlab Command Window`:

```
mex -g mx_minimum_power.cpp cvm_em64t_debug.lib
```

The files `blas.h`, `cfun.h`, `cvm.h` and `cvm_em64t_debug.lib` are in the same directory as `mx_minimum_power.cpp`.
They are the headers and library files of the [CVM Class Library](http://www.cvmlib.com/).

Then I've attached `MATLAB.exe` to `Visual Studio 2013`, using the way [explained here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/debugging-on-microsoft-windows-platforms.html).
and have set a `breakpoint` at `line40`:

[image]

When I run my `MATLAB` code, there's no error until the specified line.

[image]

But if I click on the `Step Over` button, I'll encounter the following message:

[image]

With the following information added to the `Output`:

```
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCAE9E5D in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cvm::cvmexception at memory location 0x0000000004022570.
> throw_segv_longjmp_seh_filter()
throw_segv_longjmp_seh_filter(): C++ exception
< throw_segv_longjmp_seh_filter() = EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH
```

[image]

Can you suggest me why `libmex.pdb` is needed at that line and how should I solve the issue?

---

If I stop debugging, I'll get the following information in `MATLAB Command Window`:

```
Unexpected Standard exception from MEX file.
What() is:First index value 0 is out of [1,4) range
```

---

Right before pressing the `step over` button, we have the following values for `A11[0],A12[0],A13[0],A22[0],A23[0],A33[0]`:

[image]

that are just right as my expectations, according to what `MATLAB` passes to the `MEX` function:
[image]

Maybe the problem is because of wrong allocation for matrix `A`, it is as follows just before pressing the `step over` button.

[image]

Comment: An exception is being thrown inside one of the MATLAB modules. Visual Studio tries to find corresponding code in debug database file (.pdb), to show you the source of the error, but is unable to find it, as debug information is not shipped with MATLAB (the libraries are proprietary). Disassembly is also available, but in your case it wouldn't help much.

Comment: I would suggest you to verify correctness of the array access on the line with the breakpoint. You can mouseover the variable to see it's value, or to browse values in "Autos" or "Locals" windows (menu Debug -> Windows), or in one of the "Watches" window.

Comment: I would be concerned about these very suspicious casts. Split line with the breakpoint into two: (1) reading from array into intermediate variable `auto tmp = inMatrixA11[i]` and (2) `A.set(..., tmp)`. After that, investigate program state transitions around these lines. By the way, on which iteration (`i`) does exception happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because we have the following code in lines 48 to 53 of the `cvm.h` file:

```
// 5.7 0-based indexing
#if defined (CVM_ZERO_BASED)
#   define CVM0 TINT_ZERO //!< Index base, 1  by default or 0 when \c CVM_ZERO_BASED is defined
#else
#   define CVM0 TINT_ONE  //!< Index base, 1  by default or 0 when \c CVM_ZERO_BASED is defined
#endif
```

That makes `CVM0 = 1` by default. So if we press the `Step Into(F11)` button at the specified line two times, we will get into line 34883 of the file `cvm.h`:

```
basic_schmatrix& set(tint nRow, tint nCol, TC c) throw(cvmexception)
{
    this->_set_at(nRow - CVM0, nCol - CVM0, c);
    return *this;
}
```

Press `Step Into(F11)` at line `this->_set_at(nRow - CVM0, nCol - CVM0, c);` and you'll go to the definition of the function `_set_at`:

```
// sets both elements to keep matrix hermitian, checks ranges
// zero based
void _set_at(tint nRow, tint nCol, TC val) throw(cvmexception)
{
    _check_lt_ge(CVM_OUTOFRANGE_LTGE1, nRow, CVM0, this->msize() + CVM0);
    _check_lt_ge(CVM_OUTOFRANGE_LTGE2, nCol, CVM0, this->nsize() + CVM0);
    if (nRow == nCol && _abs(val.imag()) > basic_cvmMachMin<TR>()) { // only reals on main diagonal
        throw cvmexception(CVM_BREAKS_HERMITIANITY, "real number");
    }
    this->get()[this->ld() * nCol + nRow] = val;
    if (nRow != nCol) {
        this->get()[this->ld() * nRow + nCol] = _conjugate(val);
    }
}
```

pressing `Step Over(F10)` button,you'll get the result:

[image]

so in order to get `nRow=1` and `nCol=1` and not `nRow=0` and `nCol=0`, which is out of the range `[1,4)`, you should write that line of code as:

```
A.set(2, 2, inMatrixA11[i]);
```