# run time error when using a mex file, maybe due to memory allocation

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio-2013, linear-algebra, mex

I've written a mex function named `mx_minimum_power` that I'm calling it in MATLAB as follows:

```
[Fs,Fd,pow_remained] = mx_minimum_power(A11,A12_real,A12_imag,A13_real,A13_imag,A22,A23_real,A23_imag,A33,MatSize);
```

- A11, A12_real, A13_real, A22, A23_real, A33 are `30555x1 single`
  matrices
- A12_imag, A13_imag, A23_imag are `1x1 single` variables
- MatSize is a `1x1 double` variable with the value `30555`, that is the
  size of matrices

In an iteration, each time the hermitian matrix A is constructed

[image]
and eigenvalues and eigenvectors of it should be found. So I've written the following gateway function with the help of [CVM Class Library](http://www.cvmlib.com/).

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double *arraysizePtr = NULL;
    arraysizePtr = mxGetPr(prhs[9]);
    const int arraysize = (int)*arraysizePtr;
    const int matrixDimention = 3;
    float *inMatrixA11 = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    float *inMatrixA12_real = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    float *inMatrixA12_imag = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[2]);
    float *inMatrixA13_real = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[3]);
    float *inMatrixA13_imag = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[4]);
    float *inMatrixA22 = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[5]);
    float *inMatrixA23_real = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[6]);
    float *inMatrixA23_imag = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[7]);
    float *inMatrixA33 = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[8]);
    basic_schmatrix< float, complex<float> > A(matrixDimention);
    basic_scmatrix< float, complex<float> > EigenVectors(matrixDimention);
    basic_rvector<float>EigenValues(matrixDimention);
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < arraysize; i++)
    {
        A.set(2, 2, inMatrixA11[i]);
        A.set(2, 3, complex<float>(inMatrixA12_real[i], inMatrixA12_imag[0]));
        A.set(2, 4, complex<float>(inMatrixA13_real[i], inMatrixA13_imag[0]));
        A.set(3, 3, inMatrixA22[i]);
        A.set(3, 4, complex<float>(inMatrixA23_real[i], inMatrixA23_imag[0]));
        A.set(4, 4, inMatrixA33[i]);
        try{ EigenValues = A.eig(EigenVectors);}
        catch (cvmexception& ex) {
            cout << ex.what() << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

until `line 28` that is `try{ EigenValues = A.eig(EigenVectors);}`, here I get the run-time error:
[image]
and the control jumps to line 311 of the file cvm.h, that is `line 11` of the following code:

```
CVM_NAMESPACE_BEG  

//! %Array deleter helper class  
template<typename T>
class ArrayDeleter {
public:  
    void operator () (T* d) const {
        if (d != nullptr) {
            ::delete[] d;
        }
    }
};
```

seems that something causes the array get deleted before returning the control to the gateway function but I don't know what? Because if I stop debugging and return to MATLAB, I will get:
[image]
and if I press `attempt to continue`, I'll get:
[image]
so there's no way to see which exception is thrown through the `try, catch and cout` code.

**Hint:**

- `basic_schmatrix` is a class in CVM library that is encapsulating hermitian matrices of complex numbers. See [here](http://www.cvmlib.com/doc/classbasic__schmatrix.html), [here](http://www.cvmlib.com/doc/cvm_8h.html#a212fa99240b06e41ce35af7b86363d61) and [here](http://www.cvmlib.com/doc/classbasic__schmatrix.html#a306b68775b30976d6039940e813bc7b3)
- `basic_scmatrix` is a class in CVM library that encapsulates square matrices of complex numbers. See [here](http://www.cvmlib.com/doc/classbasic__scmatrix.html), [here](http://www.cvmlib.com/doc/cvm_8h.html#aa8bc1ae10c9256c4e724dace9e82cc20) and [here](http://www.cvmlib.com/doc/classbasic__scmatrix.html#ad2427b3d536277e06e59d29bce93fac5), I've used it to allocate memory for `Eigenvectors`, because they'll be returned in the form of a the square matrix
  [image]
  in which the columns are orthonormal eigenvectors.
- `basic_rvector` is a class in CVM library for encapsulating vector of real numbers. It has been used to allocate memory for eigenvalues because as we know the eigenvalues of a hermitian matrix is real and they'll be returned in the form of the vector
  [image]
- I've used indices `2-4` instead of `1-3` because as I've explained [here CVM0=1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39432444/1245120)
- Finaly `eig` is a member function of the class `basic_schmatrix` that gets the address to the allocated memory for eigenvectors and returns an object of type `rvector`, please see [here](http://www.cvmlib.com/doc/classbasic__schmatrix.html#ae29e73687bdb6885bc31855adebd4540)

**EDIT :**
from my inspections it's not an error. The control should normally reach `line 311` of the file `CVM.h`, because it is using dynamic memory allocation and it's going to release resources when returning to the gateway function [here's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx_9vCAvXd5ka3N6Yll2SE9XUW8/view?usp=sharing) a list of where the control goes when you press `F11`s and it's not throwing an exception at all. But what's wrong with my gateway function code that causes matlab encounter such a breakpoint?

Comment: Are you sure that the matrix being deleted is `A`? Are you sure that `A.eig()` throws a C++ exception? The library might be freeing a temporary variable, and then crashing on an unrelated buffer overflow.

Comment: Also, while the link describes 1-based indexing, you seem to be using *2*-based indexing. That could cause such a crash.

Comment: @Potatoswatter What do you mean by `Also, while the link describes 1-based indexing, you seem to be using 2-based indexing`? May you clarify? which link do you mean? and about your first question I'm really not aware about what is being deleted. I'm now inspecting it through pressing `F11`s to see where does the error occure

Comment: [This link.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39432444/1245120) 0-based indexing uses indexes 0, 1, 2, and 1-based indexing uses 1, 2, 3. You are using 2, 3, 4.

Comment: @Potatoswatter if you have a look to the question or the [picture in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbjTL.png), you'll see that I once used 1,2,3 as indices but I understood that I should use 2,3,4. as I have explained in the fourth bullet "I've used indices 2-4 instead of 1-3 because as I've explained CVM0=1"