# why am I getting the error "Invalid MEX-file", while the file is in the current folder?

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio-2013, mex, armadillo

This is my current folder:
[image]
and here is the gateway function written in the file `mx_minimum_power.cpp`:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include "armaMex.hpp"

using std::complex;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double *arraysizePtr = NULL;
    arraysizePtr = mxGetPr(prhs[9]);
    const int arraysize = (int)*arraysizePtr;
    const int matrixDimention = 3;
    float *inMatrixA11 = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    float *inMatrixA12_real = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    float *inMatrixA12_imag = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[2]);
    float *inMatrixA13_real = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[3]);
    float *inMatrixA13_imag = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[4]);
    float *inMatrixA22 = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[5]);
    float *inMatrixA23_real = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[6]);
    float *inMatrixA23_imag = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[7]);
    float *inMatrixA33 = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[8]);
    Mat <complex<float>> A(matrixDimention, matrixDimention);
    Mat <complex<float>> EigenVectors(matrixDimention, matrixDimention);
    Col <float> Eigenvalues(matrixDimention);
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < arraysize; i++)
    {
        A.at(0, 0) = complex<float>(inMatrixA11[i],0);
        A.at(1, 1) = complex<float>(inMatrixA22[i],0);
        A.at(2, 2) = complex<float>(inMatrixA33[i], 0);
        A.at(0, 1) = complex<float>(inMatrixA12_real[i], inMatrixA12_imag[0]);
        A.at(1, 0) = complex<float>(inMatrixA12_real[i], -inMatrixA12_imag[0]);
        A.at(0, 2) = complex<float>(inMatrixA13_real[i], inMatrixA13_imag[0]);
        A.at(2, 0) = complex<float>(inMatrixA13_real[i], -inMatrixA13_imag[0]);
        A.at(1, 2) = complex<float>(inMatrixA23_real[i], inMatrixA23_imag[0]);
        A.at(2, 1) = complex<float>(inMatrixA23_real[i], -inMatrixA23_imag[0]);
        eig_sym(Eigenvalues, EigenVectors, A);
    }
}
```

I have build the `mx_minimum_power.mexw64` file through the following code:

```
mex -g mx_minimum_power.cpp blas_win64_MT.lib lapack_win64_MT.lib
Building with 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Professional'.
MEX completed successfully.
```

and as you see all both of the files `Arii2011_modified.m` and `mx_minimum_power.mexw64` are in the current directory.
but when I run the following function:

```
[Ps,Pd,Pv,ThetaMean,Variance] = Arii2011_Modified(MMA.Data.C11,MMA.Data.C12_imag,MMA.Data.C12_real,MMA.Data.C13_imag,MMA.Data.C13_real,MMA.Data.C22,MMA.Data.C23_imag,MMA.Data.C23_real,MMA.Data.C33);
```

in the command window, I get the error:

```
Invalid MEX-file 'D:\thesis library.Data\ALOS-PALSAR 12x2\San Francisco L
12x2\mx_minimum_power.mexw64': The specified module could not be found.
```

I guess the error is somehow related to `armadillo`, because if I convert lines 29-45 of the `mx_minimum.cpp` to comments and then rebuild the `mx_minimum_power.mexw64`, I will not get such error and the MEX file is recognized

---

This is what I have found through inspecting the `mx_minimum_power.mexw64` file in dependency walker.

[image]

Comment: Did you check your dependencies and make sure that they are accessible using the dependency walker as suggested by [the mathworks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/invalid-mex-file-error.html)

Comment: @Suever I will. but I'm really tired. if you take a look on my recent posts, you'll see that it's the third library that I'm trying. I wasted a lot of time on [cvm][http://www.cvmlib.com/], checked the dependencies, run the code through `F11`, and finally I couldn't overcome [the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41423499/1245120), then I switched to Eigen ad it had its own problem. now armadillo is facing with such an error and just one day left to the deadline of project submittion. Which linear algebra programming library would you suggest that doesn't have any problem with mex files?

Comment: @Suever mx_minimum_power is just a simple function. it is going to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a hermitian matrix, then it will calculate the phase 13 element of the outer product of eigenvectors

Comment: The problem is not with the libraries, the problem is with your expectation of how linking external libraries works.

Comment: Make sure you have the right permissions for the mex file.

Comment: @Suever I took your advise. yes, there are problems with at least 8 modules. one of them is `LAPACK_WIN64_MT.DLL` while there is a `Readme.txt` file with armadillo mex interface that emphasizes on static linking `IMPORTANT!
----------

All mex objects need to be linked _statically_ with BLAS and LAPACK
(or high-performance versions such as OpenBLAS)
in order to work correctly with Matlab.

See "armaMex_documentation.pdf" and "armaMex_demo.cpp" for example usage.` and as you know `.dll`s are for dynamic linking. what should I do to fix the problem generally?

Comment: @Dima I have. It is written by myself and as I said the error doesn't occur when I delete that parts of code that uses armadillo. The dependency walker suggests that there are problems with modules

Answer (score 0):

I added the files `blas_win64_MT.dll` and `lapack_win64_MT.dll` to the current folder and the problem got fixed
Thanks to the comment made by @suever